# JetBrains Rider: Can't change environment variable in a project profile

Tags: environment-variables, rider

I am attempting to modify a .NET project's settings profile in JetBrains Rider on Linux by changing its environment variables. However, when I click on the folder icon, I can't click to add, delete, or modify any environment variables.

[image: Folder icon]

I noticed that in [Rider's instructions on changing environment variables](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/23/rundebug-configurations-rider/), they are not showing a folder icon, but instead a "..." icon which does allow you to edit environment variables.

[image]

**My question is: How can I edit my environment variables?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under your project folder, go to:

`Properties` -> `lauchSettings.json`

Then go ahead and edit your `environmentVariables` there